Is there a way in VS Code to launch two python files and then automatically display them both side by side?
I'm trying to create a launch.json configuration that will run two python files and then show the two terminals side-by-side. It's easy to do manually but I can't figure out a way to automate it.
The closest I've come is identifying the workbench.action.terminal.join command which I can use in the Command Pallet to join two terminals, however when doing that I have to select which terminal I want to join with the currently selected terminal. I don't know how to replicate that selection using a task.
Here is the launch.json I'm using
{
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "compounds": [
            {
                "name": "Run: Server and Client",
                "configurations": ["Run: Server", "Run: Client"],
                "postDebugTask": "Join Terminals",
                "presentation": {
                    "group": "server-client",
                    "order": 1
                }
            }
        ],
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Run: Server",
                "type": "debugpy",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server.py",
                "console": "integratedTerminal",
                "presentation": {
                    "group": "server-client",
                    "order": 1
                },
                "consoleTitle": "Server"
            },
            {
                "name": "Run: Client",
                "type": "debugpy",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${workspaceFolder}/client.py",
                "console": "integratedTerminal",
                "presentation": {
                    "group": "server-client",
                    "order": 2
                },
                "consoleTitle": "Client"
            }
        ], 
}

and here is a simple tasks.json I've tried.
{
        "version": "2.0.0",    
        "tasks": [
            {
                "label": "Join Terminals",
                "type": "shell",
                "command": ["${command:workbench.action.terminal.join}"],
                "problemMatcher": []
            }
        ] 
}

I've also attempted a tasks.json using input commands like the one shown below. I did not get any results from this either.
    {
        "version": "2.0.0",    
        "tasks": [
            {
                "label": "Join Terminals",
                "type": "shell",
                "command": "echo ${input:terminalName}",
                "problemMatcher": []
            }
        ],
        "inputs": [
        {
          "id": "terminalName",
          "type": "command",
          "command": "command:workbench.action.terminal.join",
          "args": {
            "useFirstResult": true
          }
        }   ] 
}


Yes, you can achieve this in VS Code by using the "Explorer" and "Editor Groups" features. Here's a step-by-step guide:
Open the two Python files you want to launch and display side by side in the VS Code Explorer.
Make sure the Explorer is visible by clicking on the Explorer icon in the left sidebar or pressing Ctrl + Shift + E (Windows/Linux) or Cmd + Shift + E (macOS).
Open the Command Palette by pressing Ctrl + Shift + P (Windows/Linux) or Cmd + Shift + P (macOS).
Type "Python: Select Interpreter" and select the Python interpreter you want to use for both files.
Open the first Python file in the editor by clicking on it in the Explorer.
Open the Command Palette again and type "Editor: Move Editor into Next Group" (or use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl + Shift + → (Windows/Linux) or Cmd + Shift + → (macOS)). This will move the editor into a new group.
Open the second Python file in the editor by clicking on it in the Explorer. It will open in the new editor group.
You should now see both files displayed side by side. You can resize the editor groups by dragging the borders between them.
Alternatively, you can also use the "Open Editors" view to achieve this. Here's how:
Open both Python files in the editor.
Open the Command Palette and type "View: Open Editors" (or use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl + Shift + Alt + O (Windows/Linux) or Cmd + Shift + Alt + O (macOS)).
This will open the "Open Editors" view, which shows a list of all open editors.
Drag and drop the second file from the "Open Editors" view into the editor group where the first file is open. This will create a new editor group with both files side by side.
Note that you can also use the "Split Editor" feature to split a single editor into multiple panes. To do this, open a file in the editor, then click on the "Split Editor" button in the top right corner of the editor or use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl + \ (Windows/Linux) or Cmd + \ (macOS). This will split the editor into two panes, and you can open the second file in the new pane.
